# github actions detect if secret exists

Tags: github, github-actions

In one of my GitHub actions, I want to test if a secret exists before I try to use it so that I can provide the user with a more informative error message. My current strategy for doing this is to add the following step at the beginning of my action:

```
- name: check if MY_SECRET exists
  run: if [ `echo ${{secrets.MY_SECRET}} | wc -c` -lt 2 ]; then echo the secret \"MY_SECRET\" has not been made; echo please go to \"settings \> secrets \> actions\" to create it; exit 1; fi
```

This is an improvement over not having any error handling as it stops the action from proceeding, and gives the user some helpful advice, however I'd like to know if there is a 'better' solution. In particular, does GitHub have a recommendation for how to handle this kind of situation? Is there some other action from market place for example that I can call? (I checked market place but couldn't find anything to do this, however I may have missed something).

This seems to me like a functionality that I might want to reuse frequently, so assuming there is no marketplace or in built solution, I intend to make my own action which I can call that will do this for me. I have noticed a lot of actions on market place are implemented in node. Is this considered preferable to bash? Is there any reason I should not implement this functionality in bash?

Finally, as I am working with secrets here, I'd like to keep security in mind. Please have that in mind when proposing any solutions. Also please critique my current solution with security in mind.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Using encrypted secrets in a workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#using-encrypted-secrets-in-a-workflow)"

> Command-line processes may be visible to other users (using the `ps` command) or captured by [security audit events](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/component-updates/command-line-process-auditing).
> To help protect secrets, consider using environment variables, STDIN, or other mechanisms supported by the target process.

And:

> Secrets cannot be directly referenced in [`if:` conditionals](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsif).
>
> Instead, consider setting secrets as job-level environment variables, then referencing the environment variables to [conditionally run steps in the job](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#using-contexts-to-access-environment-variable-values).

In your case:

```yaml
steps:
      - name: "check is MY_SECRET exists"
        env: 
            super_secret: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET }}
        if: ${{ env.super_secret == '' }}
        run: 'echo "echo the secret \"MY_SECRET\" has not been made; echo please go to \"settings \> secrets \> actions\" to create it"
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why this is an improvement on my current solution? Is it more secure? If so why? Are there any additional benefits? Thanks

Comment: @Mathew The elaboration was done in the first section. Avoid run command-line, use environment variables as the documentation recommends.

Comment: ok thanks. Is there a good way to know when it is a good idea to run command-line? For example, your solution still runs command line. Why would this be a recommended use case for commandline?

Comment: @Mathew In my case, it does not echo the secret itself, only a message based on the `if env` condition.

Comment: great. Thanks for the clarification. Also, I think you meant to do `env.super_secret` on line 5. Also, would you recommend refactoring this code as an action that I can call, or just leaving it as is?

Comment: @Mathew I used the same syntax as in https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#using-contexts-to-access-environment-variable-values.  And for such a short condition, you can leave it as is.

Comment: Thanks for the advice regarding refactoring. This covers all my concerns so I'll accept the answer now. I tried your code with `env.MY_SECRET` and it did not work correctly, however it works when I use `env.super_secret` like I suggested. This makes sense to me as `super_secret` is in  `env` however `MY_SECRET` is in `secrets`. However maybe I have made an error. In anycase, thanks a lot for your time, I greatly appreciate it.