# Best practices for uploading to nexus in a GitHub action using the nexus API

Tags: github, curl, github-actions, nexus

In a GitHub action, I am uploading a file using cURL to a [nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/products/nexus-repository) repository using the nexus API.

Here is the relevant code from my action:

```
name: upload zip file to nexus
run: curl -v -k -u username:${{secrets.credential}} --upload-file file.zip https://my-company-nexus.canadacentral.cloudapp.azure.com/repository/path/to/file.zip
```

Although this works fine, I'd like to know if there is a better solution. In particular, I am under the impression that it is bad practice to have a secret used in a run command. How can I avoid this? Is there a built in GitHub action that works with cURL? If not, is there a good 3rd party action instead?

Comment: What makes you think it is bad practice to have a secret in a run command?

Comment: I got that impression from @VonC from his answer to my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72925899/github-actions-detect-if-secret-exists however I may have missunderstood him. In particular this comment: "Avoid run command-line, use environment variables as the documentation recommends." Also my question is more broadly about how this code can be improved. For example, is there a market place action I should use that, say, has better logging? What is the 'suggested' or 'standard' or 'GitHub recommended' way of doing this type of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Avoid run command-line, use environment variables as the documentation recommends." part referenced the [`if:` conditional "Example: Using secrets" section](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-secrets=):

> Secrets cannot be directly referenced in `if: conditionals`.
> Instead, consider setting secrets as job-level environment variables, then referencing the environment variables to conditionally run steps in the job.

Since that environment variable (including in your example) is referenced as `${{secret.xxx}}`, that allows to GitHub-ci et its GitHub runner to manage said environment variable differently.

Namely, its display would be obfuscated (`*****`) and its memory footprint minimized. Your `run:` command should be fine.